# how to disable fling of a scrollView

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I want to disable the fling gesture of a scrollview and it does not seem to be working..  I thought it would be as easy as creating a basic class that extends scrollview and @`Overriding`  the `onFling` method.  but eclipse is giving me an error to remove the @Override:

any ideas how to disable the fling

```
public class ScrollViewNoFling extends ScrollView {

    /**
     * @param context
     * @param attrs
     * @param defStyle
     */
    public ScrollViewNoFling(Context context) {

        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public ScrollViewNoFling(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        super(context, attrs);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public ScrollViewNoFling(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

   @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I solved same problem with Override fling method. If you override fling method on your ScrollViewNoFling class and not call super.fling on this method, you gonna have not-fling-handled scrollView.

```
@Override
public void fling (int velocityY)
{
    /*Scroll view is no longer gonna handle scroll velocity.
     * super.fling(velocityY);
    */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be fling and not onFling.
Please refer to the official [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#fling%28int%29)

Comment: Also note that `onFling()` is a part of [GestureDetector.OnGestureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html). It is a valid method, just not in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to using `fling()` instead of `onFling()`, you need to pay attention to your return values.

As per the documentation for [onFling()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.OnGestureListener.html#onFling%28android.view.MotionEvent,%20android.view.MotionEvent,%20float,%20float%29):

> **Returns**
>
> true if the event is consumed, else false

If you want to catch the event and do nothing, return true. Otherwise, the event will be passed on to some other method/class to attempt to handle it.